# Clarificantion on the proof of a differentiation theorem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]
[image]

I don't really follow the part of proof that states The other partial derivatives are $g_b=(f(b,t)$ and $g_a=-f(a,t)$. Can someone explain this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is clear is you do it separately. Let $c_1\in\mathbb{R}$ any fixed point and consider$$
g_b(t):=\int_0^{b(t)}f(x)dx .
$$
Then, by the fundamental calculus' theorem and by using chain's rule we obtain $\tfrac{d}{dt}g_b(t)=f(b(t))b'(t)$. On the other hand, for any $c_2\in\mathbb{R}$ if you consider a function of the form $$
g_a(t):=\int_{a(t)}^{c_2} f(x)dx,
$$
in the same fashion we obtain $$
\dfrac{d}{dt}g_a(t)=-\dfrac{d}{dt}\int_{c_2}^{a(t)}f(x)dx=-f(a(t))a'(t).
$$
Finally, if the integration domain is fixed and assuming everything is regular enough we obtain $$
g(t)=\int_{c_1}^{c_2}f(x,t)dx \quad \implies \quad \dfrac{d}{dt}g(t)=\int_{c_1}^{c_2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)dt.
$$
Therefore, for a function depending in all of the previous forms $$
g(t)=\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(x,t)dx,
$$
from the previous computations we obtain $$
\dfrac{d}{dt}g(t)=f(b(t),t)b'(t)-f(a(t),t)a'(t)+\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)dx.
$$